# Can't add integration_test package

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone help me? Why can't I add this package to my `pubspec.yaml`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume your project name is also `integration_test`
, change the name of your project as when running the `pub get` command, flutter reads the project name instead of the library name.

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependencies to the dev_dependencies section of the app’s `pubspec.yaml` file, specifying the Flutter SDK as the location of the package.

```
dev_dependencies:
  integration_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

More documentation on [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) with example.

Comment: I try to add this in my pubspec.yaml and the error show "The dev dependency on integration_test is unnecessary because there is also a normal dependency on that package.
Try removing the dev dependency."